# Autofac, upgrade to version 4.0.0 is missing ConfigurationSettingsReader

Tags: c#, autofac

The latest documentation still refer's to the `ConfigurationSettingsReader` class which seems to be missing from the updated `Autofac.Configuration` assembly.

How do get the equivalent of this code to function in **version 4.0.0.**

I have this configuration:

```
<section name="dependencies"  
   type="Autofac.Configuration.SectionHandler, Autofac.Configuration" />

  ...

<dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module type="MyModule, MyAssembly.Service" />
  </modules>
</dependencies>
```

and this code.

```
// register the application overrides.
container.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("dependencies"));
```

**additionally,**

the new autofac.configuration assembly is the only autofac assembly dependent on framework version 4.5.1, and not 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The 4.0 version of Autofac.Configuration *only* supports the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` manner of configuration.** There is no `ConfigurationSettingsReader` in the 4.0 version nor is the configuration XML the same format as it used to be.

[I have updated the documentation to be more clear about this.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) Sorry for the confusion.

Core Autofac and the dependent integration libraries were originally *all* released at .NET 4.5.1+ support when .NET Core was released. This was for a variety of reasons including some dependency and testing libraries only supporting .NET 4.5.1 during development.

Since then, core Autofac and a couple of the integration libraries have been able to go back and support .NET 4.5 but that change is slow to trickle through. It may not be possible for all the integration libraries to go back. I pushed [v4.0.1 of Autofac.Configuration](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Configuration/4.0.1) for .NET 4.5 compatiblility...

**HOWEVER**:

[**.NET 4.5 IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED BY MICROSOFT.**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/) You will start running into more of these incompatibility issues with Autofac and other dependencies if you decide not to upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 or higher. I would strongly recommend doing that as soon as you can so you don't run into further issues.

Comment: The documentation still refers to `ConfigurationSettingsReader` in the `Flexibility to Override` paragraph. Can you correct with a new example please?

Comment: The docs in the "pre-4.0" section do, yes. That still works in pre-4.0.

Comment: Ohh, I had not  seen was "pre-4.0" section... I am sorry, but I do not understand how to getting the configuration in 4.0 and later... I am trying to follow the quick-start guide but something does not working.. Can you add a full example there?
Here is what I am trying to do, but something it's wrong:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454684/read-modules-from-web-config-in-autofac